# Possible to recreate lakes?

Tags: terraria

In my first world I often demolished my natural lakes and oceans.

Now I'm sweeping up the angler quests, but I don't have a lot of lakes left.

Is there a way to create new lakes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on how you did the destroying. If you trapped it all in dirt, then breaking it up restores the water.

But summoning more of it from nowhere... [Dry / Liquid Bombs](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Liquid_bombs) are a way to infinitely produce liquids. You need Obsidian-type crates to get the first one to convert into a water bomb.

...

Whether the Angler ever offers impossible quests, and it might just be easier to destroy biomes to keep the Angler from selecting them, perhaps.

...

If you're in Hardmode and getting enough possible Angler quests to be worth it, you could just tough it out and hope for the [Bottomless Water Bucket](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Bottomless_Water_Bucket) Angler reward.

You also only need one lake per biome, so if you have multiple Sky Lakes, you could break one and use its water for another biome.

Then there's just using regular buckets to draw water from the Sea to wherever you need it. Tedious, but it's *a* method, however unadvised.

Comment: You can also use the [Bottomless Water Bucket](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Bottomless_Water_Bucket) once you get it, though that requires a Hardmode world and some luck with the Angler.

Comment: @ChrisHayes - Oh, yeah. I have that but discounted it since they were clearly on the Angler path. ... But it does make sense to add it in. "Grind Angler Quests in Hard Mode until you get bucket."

Comment: I don't think it is safe to assume that "the angler won't offer impossible quests". If you don't have a jungle fishing spot, and he offers a quest for it, you'd simply have to wait until the next day to get a new quest.

Comment: @nightsurfer - Yeah, I'm not trying to say whether he does or not. I mean "If he doesn't offer impossible quests, then killing the tricky biomes so he'll stop offering those quests, is an option."

Answer (score 0):

Post-1.4 update, the bottomless water bucket is available pre-hardmode. The angler rewards it on the 25th quest or with 1/70 chance after the 10th quest.

You're out of luck if you happen to be in a world with zero water whatsoever (e.g. in a skyblock challenge), but if you've got at least one bucket's worth of water, you can use various volumetric water simulation glitches (a few are detailed [here](https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Liquids#_Desktop_version,_Console_version,_and_Mobile_version)) to slowly produce additional water.